# iPhone - get the Content Size of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am opening the local Pdf File in my UIWebView and and than trying to adjust the size of UIWebview such that WebView height become equal to WebView Content height i am using this line of code to get the height of WebView Content

```
- (float) getWebViewContentHeight:(UIWebView *)view
{


    CGRect aFrame               = view.frame;

    aFrame.size.height  = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    view.frame              = aFrame;

    return view.frame.size.height;
}
```

this code is working perfectly on iOS 4.3 but not working on iOS 5.0 can any one help me plz how to get the content size of webView or make this code working for iOS 5 as well

Comment: What error or problem you are facing please mention.

Comment: sizeThatFits is not working in iOS 5 when i run the above code in iOS 4.3 it give me the exact height of UIWebView Content but when i run this code on iOS 5.0 it gives the height of UIWebview not the height of UIWebView Content

Answer (score 6):

Accessing the content is a bit tricky but here I'll show 2 ways to do it.

**1. The ugly way**

Using JS to query the document properties:

```
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"] floatValue],
                                [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue]);
```

**2. The less ugly way**

`UIWebView` is a composite object which contains an internal `UIScrollView`. Starting from iOS 5.0, you can try grabbing this scroll view and using its `contentSize` property directly as `webView.scrollView.contentSize`. In case you need to maintain compatibility with iOS 4.3 and before, you have to do some black magic to get the scroll view:

```
UIScrollView* webScrollView = nil;
for ( UIView* subview in [webView subviews] )
{
    if ( [subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] )
    {
        webScrollView = (UIScrollView*)subview;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: in first case it is returning 0.0000 and in the second case it is returning the height of webView not the height of the content of WebView;

Comment: are you trying `webScrollView.contentSize`?

Comment: Yes webScrollView.contentSize.height

Comment: The API has changed, instead of looping through subviews, you can access a `UIWebView`'s internal scroll view by using `[(UIWebView) scrollView]`

Comment: `webview.scrollview.contentSize` always returns the height never returns a height smaller than the current height. You can only get bigger

Answer (score 0):

The webViewDidFinishLoad method may be called more than once, and the first value returned by sizeThatFits is only some portion of what the final size should be. Then for whatever reason the next call to sizeThatFits when webViewDidFinishLoad fires again will incorrectly return the same value it did before! This will happen randomly for the same content as if it's some kind of concurrency problem. Maybe this behaviour has changed over time, because I'm building for iOS 5 and have also found that sizeToFit works in much the same way (although previously this didn't?)

I have settled on this simple solution:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{        
    CGFloat height = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat width = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    frame.size.width = width;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

Swift (2.2):

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

```
if let heightString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.height"),
    widthString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.width"),
    height = Float(heightString),
    width = Float(widthString) {

    var rect = webView.frame
    rect.size.height = CGFloat(height)
    rect.size.width = CGFloat(width)
    webView.frame = rect
}
```

}

Update: I have found as mentioned in the comments this doesn't seem to catch the case where the content has shrunk. Not sure if it's true for all content and OS version, give it a try.