# How to set height of UIWebView based on html content?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I want to set height of UIWebview based on HTML content. I am getting the size of a string, but not getting the actual size due to paragraph, bold, different font size, etc.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Webview got a scroll, so you probably dont need that.

Comment: I have webview in each row in UITablView. I am not getting every row's webview height at heightForRowAtIndexPath. So i am confuse how to set Each row height in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually use these methods, to set `UIWebview` frame as it's content size:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 5.0f;
    webView.frame = frame;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGSize mWebViewTextSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)]; // Pass about any size
    CGRect mWebViewFrame = webView.frame;
    mWebViewFrame.size.height = mWebViewTextSize.height;
    webView.frame = mWebViewFrame;

    //Disable bouncing in webview
    for (id subview in webView.subviews) {
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
            [subview setBounces:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

They are automatically called (if you set `webView`'s delegate to this class), when `WebView` has finished loading it's content.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the subviews to find the scroll view? just use webView.scrollView. I also think that you should only set bounces in viewDidLoad since it only needs to happen once. (It's still a fine answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment - good idea :) . The code I posted is really old, from time when scrollview was not accessible directly.

Answer (score 8):

Well, every web view has a UIScrollView built into it, so I would try waiting for the page to load and then tapping into the scroll view's contentSize property to get the height of the page.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGFloat height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
}
```

Comment: in this code what is height.it is any property for web view height.

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{     
    height= [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight"] floatValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview.delegate = self;
    [webview loadHTMLString:@"<div id='foo' style='background: red'>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>" baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *output = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").offsetHeight;"];
    NSLog(@"height: %@", output);
}
```

see also [How to determine UIWebView height based on content, within a variable height UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745160/how-to-determine-uiwebview-height-based-on-content-within-a-variable-height-uit)

[Calculate UIWebView height depending on its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715524/calculate-uiwebview-height-depending-on-its-content)

Comment: But i have UIWebview in UITableView & each row have UIWebView so how i calculate because table height set before cellForRowAtIndex called.

Answer (score 0):

If you  have webview in tableviewcell, in heightForRowAtIndexPath set the height of cell to height of NSAttributedString size as following.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [NSString  getHTMLAttributedString:@"HTML Content"];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGRect paragraphRect =     [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:size
                                 options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                                 context:nil];
    return paragraphRect.size.height;
}

+(NSAttributedString *) getHTMLAttributedString:(NSString *) string{
    NSError *errorFees=nil;
    NSString *sourceFees = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"<span style=\"font-family: 'Roboto-Light';font-size: 14px\">%@</span>",string];
    NSMutableAttributedString* strFees = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[sourceFees dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                                 options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                           NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]}
                                                                      documentAttributes:nil error:&errorFees];
    return strFees;

}
```