# Dynamic height of UIWebView with auto layout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a problem with setting the height of an `UIWebView` dynamically. The webview loads a product description which contains html. I want the `UIWebView` to change its height based on the contents of the description. The parent scrollview should also change its height, but then based on the height of the `UIWebView`.

Can anyone explain to me how I can achieve the desired behavior of my views?

This is my view hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715524/calculate-uiwebview-height-depending-on-its-content ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the content size of a UIWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

Comment: Need an answer that supports Autolayout

Answer (score 9):

You have to add some code in the delegate method of UIWebView named webViewDidFinishLoad. Here is what you can do:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
      CGRect frame = webView.frame;
      frame.size.height = 1;
      webView.frame = frame;
      CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
      frame.size = fittingSize;
      webView.frame = frame;

      NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);

      yourScrollView.contentSize = webView.bounds.size; 
}
```

The same thing can also be achieved using javascript to find the right height which is as follow:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect oldBounds = [[self webView] bounds];
    CGFloat height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"NEW HEIGHT %f", height);
    [webView setBounds:CGRectMake(oldBounds.origin.x, oldBounds.origin.y, oldBounds.size.width, height)];
    yourScrollView.contentSize = webView.bounds.size;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But extremely inaccurate. I get content cut off

Comment: To get accurate result, Use observer for contentSize to webView.scrollView

Answer (score 5):

I actually had the same problem recently and ended up figuring it out and putting together a [sample project](https://github.com/shawnwall/WebViewAutoLayout) on github.

Comment: For the record, I have searched high and low for this, and your project was the best help in getting all the auto layout constraints sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a constant height constraint on your WebView and change that dynamically once you calculate the height from the response.

Also constraint between a child view and a parent view can be achieved by this method in NSLayoutConstraint

```
+ (id)constraintWithItem:(id)view1 attribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attr1 relatedBy:(NSLayoutRelation)relation toItem:(id)view2 attribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attr2 multiplier:(CGFloat)multiplier constant:(CGFloat)c
```

Comment: I have a constant height constraint on the webview, how and where can I change the height? Is is in the webviewdidfinishload method?